# Reactjs: Rendering raw html on the client with context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm trying to integrate with a 3rd party library which displays some raw html that is returned from a function call as a popup.  I figured out that I can just use `renderToString` to render my component and return it.

```
  _popup(id) {
    var foo = _getFoo(id);
    return React.renderToString(
        <Selectable>
          <FooMedia foo={foo} />
        </Selectable>
      );
  },
```

This works fine and the html is properly displayed. The problem I am having is that I'm using React Intl which expects a `messages` object to be available in the component context.  I initially set this up when I bootstrap my app like this:

```
  React.render(
    <Handler
      params={state.params}
      locales={'en-US'}
      formats={formats}
      messages={messages} 
    />,
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
```

But the context doesn't get passed down since I'm rendering a component outside of the component hierarchy. How do I set the context for the component fragment? I found `withContext` but that uses a callback and the 3rd party library doesn't expect a callback.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just set the messages property in your top-level component in renderToString?

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't seem to work.  The Intl component still throws with message not found.

Comment: Does your top-level component have ReactIntl.IntlMixin as a mixin?

Comment: I tried including the mixin in my `Selectable` component and adding a `messages={messages}` prop but that didn't help.